# Laravel5 cashier downloadInvoice() permission denied error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Unable to download pdf generated with laravel 5 cashier and phantomjs. Throws following error:

```
ProcessFailedException in Process.php line 233: The command "/PROJECT/vendor/laravel/cashier/src/Laravel/Cashier/bin/linux-x86_64/phantomjs invoice.js /PROJECT/storage/framework/48dc273eaff3a0adaab8aa4f5b1d73df.pdf" failed.
Exit Code: 126(Invoked command cannot execute)

Output:
================


Error Output:
================
sh: 1: /PROJECT/vendor/laravel/cashier/src/Laravel/Cashier/bin/linux-x86_64/phantomjs: Permission denied
```

I checked storage/framework/ directory pdf has been created with permission 644 and www-data. My storage directory has 777 permission and user say xproject

Can anyone help me to get rid of this error?

Comment: This works well on local, It seems permission issue only. But not sure where it is actually

Comment: Which user is running the command?

Comment: This is generated by laravel itself. And storage directory has other user. Not sure what you mean

Comment: Laravel is not generating the error, the error is coming from the user who is trying to run the process. If storage directory is owned by another user as you say who is not the Apache user, you'll run into permission errors.

Comment: Ya I agree laravel is not part of it mainly
Its permission issue purely. But what I mean to say is pdf generated using laravel cashier has user - www-data and storage directory is created by different user called xproject, is this causing the issue? If yes how can I fix this

Comment: That's your problem then, xproject does not have permission to write to storage, only read as you stated above with permissions set to 644. Test with permissions 666 and see if it works.

Comment: K, is there any way to add permission in laravel cashier downloadInvoice?

Comment: Are you talking about a route permission? Because you're facing a file system permission. What I suggested above was to try something like chmod -R 666 storage to see if that resolves the problem?

Comment: My storage directory has 777 permission

Comment: My last thought is check if it's 777 recursively through storage and not just on the storage directory itself

Comment: Yes it is recursive to all internal storage directory

Comment: Did you ever solve that ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same error and after much searching I found this post https://alfrednutile.info/posts/149 by Alfred Nutile

You solve the issue by adding execute permissions to the bin folder recursively:

```
chmod -R +x vendor/laravel/cashier/src/Laravel/Cashier/bin
```